# RegEx with reference to char being replaced

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using a regular expression to replace all characters other than `"^"` and `" "` like so:

```
var s = string.replace(/[^\^ ]/g,"X");
```

It works, but as you can see, it's replacing all non-blacklisted characters with an `X`. This is temporary. I want to be able to wrap, not replace, all non-blacklisted characters with a  tag.

For example, assume the string was 'foo', I'd want to use regex to result in:

```
<span>f</span><span>o</span><span>o</span>
```

Is this possible, or will I have to iterate through the string manually and do the wrapping myself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can replace by

```
<span>$&</span>
```

`$&` contains the value of the whole match and thus will surround each unwanted character with a `span` tag:

```
>> 'foo'.replace(/[^\^ ]/g, '<span>$&</span>') 
"<span>f</span><span>o</span><span>o</span>"
```

You can also add a `+` after the character class in your regex if you want whole sequences of unwanted characters surrounded instead:

```
>> 'foo'.replace(/[^\^ ]+/g, '<span>$&</span>') 
"<span>foo</span>"
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use grouping, and you can then reference back with `$n`, with `n` standing for the group number. You can group with `()`. Also, `^` does not need to be escaped in a character class.

In this case, you only want one group, so:

```
"foo ^ bar".replace(/([^^ ])/g, "<span>$1</span>");
// "<span>f</span><span>o</span><span>o</span> ^ <span>b</span><span>a</span><span>r</span>"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var s = string.replace(/([^\^ ])/g,"<span>$1</span>");
```